# Erro no comando self.bntInsert["command"] = self.inserirUsuario

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-kivy

Ola pessoal como sou novo no python preciso de um auxilio nesse código esta com o seguinte erro File **"/root/PycharmProjects/SistemaVenda/venv/App.py"**, line 113

```
    self.bntInsert["command"] = self.inserirUsuario
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Se alguem puder me ajudar agradeço muito.

```
   '''App.py (Interface)'''

from Usuarios import Usuarios
from tkinter import *
from tokenize import *


class Application:
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.fonte = ("Verdana", "8")

        self.container1 = Frame(master)
        self.container1["pady"] = 10
        self.container1.pack()
        self.container2 = Frame(master)
        self.container2["padx"] = 20
        self.container2["pady"] = 5
        self.container2.pack()
        self.container3 = Frame(master)
        self.container3["padx"] = 20
        self.container3["pady"] = 5
        self.container3.pack()
        self.container4 = Frame(master)
        self.container4["padx"] = 20
        self.container4["pady"] = 5
        self.container4.pack()
        self.container5 = Frame(master)
        self.container5["padx"] = 20
        self.container5["pady"] = 5
        self.container5.pack()
        self.container6 = Frame(master)
        self.container6["padx"] = 20
        self.container6["pady"] = 5
        self.container6.pack()
        self.container7 = Frame(master)
        self.container7["padx"] = 20
        self.container7["pady"] = 5
        self.container7.pack()
        self.container8 = Frame(master)
        self.container8["padx"] = 20
        self.container8["pady"] = 10
        self.container8.pack()
        self.container9 = Frame(master)
        self.container9["pady"] = 15
        self.container9.pack()

        self.titulo = Label(self.container1, text="Informe os dados :")
        self.titulo["font"] = ("Calibri", "9", "bold")
        self.titulo.pack()

        self.lblidusuario = Label(self.container2,
                                  text="idUsuario:", font=self.fonte, width=10)
        self.lblidusuario.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.txtidusuario = Entry(self.container2)
        self.txtidusuario["width"] = 10
        self.txtidusuario["font"] = self.fonte
        self.txtidusuario.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.btnBuscar = Button(self.container2, text="Buscar",
                                font=self.fonte, width=10)
        self.btnBuscar["command"] = self.buscarUsuario
        self.btnBuscar.pack(side=RIGHT)

        self.lblnome = Label(self.container3, text="Nome:",
                             font=self.fonte, width=10)
        self.lblnome.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.txtnome = Entry(self.container3)
        self.txtnome["width"] = 25
        self.txtnome["font"] = self.fonte
        self.txtnome.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.lbltelefone = Label(self.container4, text="Telefone:",
                                 font=self.fonte, width=10)
        self.lbltelefone.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.txttelefone = Entry(self.container4)
        self.txttelefone["width"] = 25
        self.txttelefone["font"] = self.fonte
        self.txttelefone.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.lblemail = Label(self.container5, text="E-mail:",
                              font=self.fonte, width=10)
        self.lblemail.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.txtemail = Entry(self.container5)
        self.txtemail["width"] = 25
        self.txtemail["font"] = self.fonte
        self.txtemail.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.lblusuario = Label(self.container6, text="Usuário:",
                                font=self.fonte, width=10)
        self.lblusuario.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.txtusuario = Entry(self.container6)
        self.txtusuario["width"] = 25
        self.txtusuario["font"] = self.fonte
        self.txtusuario.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.lblsenha = Label(self.container8, text="Senha:",
        font=self.fonte, width=10)
        self.lblsenha.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.txtsenha = Entry(self.container7)
        self.txtsenha["width"] = 25
        self.txtsenha["show"] = "*"
        self.txtsenha["font"] = self.fonte
        self.txtsenha.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.bntInsert = Button(self.container8, text="Inserir",
        font=self.fonte, width=12
        self.bntInsert["command"] = self.inserirUsuario
        self.bntInsert.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.bntAlterar = Button(self.container8, text="Alterar",
        font=self.fonte, width=12)
        self.bntAlterar["command"] = self.alterarUsuario
        self.bntAlterar.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.bntExcluir = Button(self.container8, text="Excluir",
        font=self.fonte, width=12)
        self.bntExcluir["command"] = self.excluirUsuario
        self.bntExcluir.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.lblmsg = Label(self.container9, text="")
        self.lblmsg["font"] = ("Verdana", "9", "italic")
        self.lblmsg.pack()


def inserirUsuario(self):
    user = Usuarios()

    user.nome = self.txtnome.get()
    user.telefone = self.txttelefone.get()
    user.email = self.txtemail.get()
    user.usuario = self.txtusuario.get()
    user.senha = self.txtsenha.get()

    self.lblmsg["text"] = user.insertUser()

    self.txtidusuario.delete(0, END)
    self.txtnome.delete(0, END)
    self.txttelefone.delete(0, END)
    self.txtemail.delete(0, END)
    self.txtusuario.delete(0, END)
    self.txtsenha.delete(0, END)


def alterarUsuario(self):
    user = Usuarios()

    user.idusuario = self.txtidusuario.get()
    user.nome = self.txtnome.get()
    user.telefone = self.txttelefone.get()
    user.email = self.txtemail.get()
    user.usuario = self.txtusuario.get()
    user.senha = self.txtsenha.get()

    self.lblmsg["text"] = user.updateUser()

    self.txtidusuario.delete(0, END)
    self.txtnome.delete(0, END)
    self.txttelefone.delete(0, END)
    self.txtemail.delete(0, END)
    self.txtusuario.delete(0, END)
    self.txtsenha.delete(0, END)


def excluirUsuario(self):
    user = Usuarios()

    user.idusuario = self.txtidusuario.get()

    self.lblmsg["text"] = user.deleteUser()

    self.txtidusuario.delete(0, END)
    self.txtnome.delete(0, END)
    self.txttelefone.delete(0, END)
    self.txtemail.delete(0, END)
    self.txtusuario.delete(0, END)
    self.txtsenha.delete(0, END)


def buscarUsuario(self):
    user = Usuarios()

    idusuario = self.txtidusuario.get()

    self.lblmsg["text"] = user.selectUser(idusuario)

    self.txtidusuario.delete(0, END)
    self.txtidusuario.insert(INSERT, user.idusuario)

    self.txtnome.delete(0, END)
    self.txtnome.insert(INSERT, user.nome)

    self.txttelefone.delete(0, END)
    self.txttelefone.insert(INSERT, user.telefone)

    self.txtemail.delete(0, END)
    self.txtemail.insert(INSERT, user.email)

    self.txtusuario.delete(0, END)
    self.txtusuario.insert(INSERT, user.usuario)

    self.txtsenha.delete(0, END)
    self.txtsenha.insert(INSERT, user.senha)


root = Tk()
Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: É Python 2 ou 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**É erro de digitação:**

```
self.bntInsert = Button(self.container8, text="Inserir",
font=self.fonte, width=12
self.bntInsert["command"] = self.inserirUsuario
```

Falta um `)` depois do `width=12`, **deveria ser**

```
self.bntInsert = Button(self.container8, text="Inserir",
font=self.fonte, width=12)
self.bntInsert["command"] = self.inserirUsuario
```

Comment: Obrigado @guilherme Nascimento